# Terraform init Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: S3 bucket does not exist

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

Hi i have an issue with terraform not being able to see the s3 bucket when i specify it as a backend

```
aws --profile terraform s3api create-bucket --bucket "some_name_here" --region "eu-west-2" \
          --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint="eu-west-2"
```

**terraform init**

```
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...

Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: S3 bucket does not exist.

The referenced S3 bucket must have been previously created. If the S3 bucket
was created within the last minute, please wait for a minute or two and try
again.

Error: NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist
    status code: 404, request id: QYJT8KP0W4TM986A, host id: a7R1EOOnIhP6YzDcKd66zdyCJ8wk6lVom/tohsc0ipUe5yEJK1/V4bLGX9khi4q4/J7d4BgYXCc=
```

**backend.tf**

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "some_name_here"
    key    = "networking/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-2"
  }
}
```

**provider.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "eu-west-2"
  shared_credentials_file = "$HOME/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "terraform"
}
```

I can see the bucket in the dashboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using a profile in the command to create the bucket. Therefore, you probably need to export a variable in the environment running terraform to use this same profile. I imagine terraform without this profile or another with sufficient permissions is unable to read from the bucket.

```
export AWS_PROFILE=terraform
terraform init
```

Alternatively, you can pass the [profile](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/s3#profile) into the backend configuration, like:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "some_name_here"
    key     = "networking/terraform.tfstate"
    profile = "terraform"
    region  = "eu-west-2"
  }
}
```

---

To summarize, the most simple configuration is:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "some_name_here"
    key     = "networking/terraform.tfstate"
    region  = "eu-west-2"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
}
```

then:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=terraform
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket "some_name_here" --region "eu-west-2" --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint="eu-west-2"
terraform init
```

Comment: Right, in my aws/credentials i have 2 profiles, a default one and a profile called [terraform]. i assume it should be using the terraform profile?

Comment: In any case how do i make terraform use the terraform aws profile i have specified in my aws credentials

Comment: See the link and configuration I added in the answer.

Comment: thanks will i have issues anywhere else by having 2 profiles in aws/credentials? im wondering if the terraform cli will provision  ifnrastructure using the default credentails instead of my the profile i am after. ideally is there a way to set the terraform cli to use terraform profile

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. You can have as many named profiles as you want. Neither terraform nor aws care. They only care about which one you tell it to use. If you don't specify `default` is used. If you do, the most explicit is used. i.e. If you set it end backend configuration, that will be use. If you don't, but you have it in the environment, via `AWS_PROFILE`, that one will be used.

Comment: Ye i guess i was asking how do i globally specify the terraform profile as the oen i want to use, rather than defining it explicity in the terrform backend.tf

Comment: I tried setting AWS_PROFILE to terraform but it did not work, same 404

Comment: I see, yes that is much better. Specifying it in the backend configuration is not great, because then others must define this profile too, so it is best as you say, for terraform to expect the environment to provide the correct credentials. Therefore, the best solution is to export `AWS_PROFILE`.

Comment: How did you do that? I do this all the time. Just like above, export the profile I want, then run terraform.

Comment: It is also possible that this profile has permissions to create the bucket, but not read and write to it as terraform requires.

Comment: hmm i'm not so sure, i added a file to the bucket using the dsahboard and then `aws --profile terraform s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "<redacted>"` it correctly showed me the file

Comment: How are you exporting the profile then running terraform. Same line? Different lines? You should even be able to do `AWS_PROFILE=terraform terraform init`.

Comment: yeah just like that, i also remember you can sepcify a provider aws with reference to terraform profile

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I changed that comment to remove the `;`. It may not work with it because it is a separate command.

Comment: If your backend configuration does not set `profile`, and your environment does set `AWS_PROFILE`, that profile will be used. I'm unsure what to recommend beyond that.

Comment: i tried the updated one, still same issue

Comment: Your provider should not have anything about credentials. At least that is most simple. Just `region` in provider, and just `bucket`, `key`, and `region` in backend configuration. Then `AWS_PROFILE` in environment.

Comment: Actually none of this mattered, once i  deleted the `.terraform` folder and `.terraform.lock.hcl` it started working with my original configuration. It seems like some older credentails might have been cached in that file